# What is -DUNIX flag use for in gcc/g++ compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I recently building an application using Qt Creator to run on a embedded Linux board.
Inside the application, I have to build some library then link them to the main Qt application.
It takes me few hours try to compile the code because compiler keep yelling at me that your c header file has syntax errors.

```
typedef uint32 BioAPI_RETURN;
typedef BioAPI_RETURN (BioAPI *BioAPI_ModuleEventHandler)
    (const BioAPI_UUID *BSPUuid,
    void* AppNotifyCallbackCtx,
    BioAPI_DEVICE_ID DeviceID,
    uint32 Reserved,
    BioAPI_MODULE_EVENT EventType);
```

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRsuy.png)

Luckily, the library come with a Makefile. I look into it and add those flag one by one to QMake (eventually it parse to g++ compiler).
The magic flag is -DUNIX. After add it, the code build fine, no more error.
Then I test to remove that flag and build with gcc and g++. That error occur again.

I have try to find some information about that flag on the Internet but no luck yet.
Do anyone have some information about that flag?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Welcome to SO. That option simply defines the macro `UNIX`. This can be tested in the code using `#ifdef UNIX`. I would assume that the type `BioAPI` might only be defined if that flag is set. When you search GCC options, it is option `D` with argument `UNIX`.

Answer (score 1):

The `-D` option [defines a macro that expands to the value `1`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

This is commonly used for conditional compilation of source code using `defined()` or `#ifdef`/`#ifndef`.